# test unitarios con dokers

Tags: nodejs, mongoose, docker, jest

Hola estoy en un proyecto en donde estoy trabajando con Dockers y poseo dos imágenes una de Nodejs y la otra de Mongo a través del Dockerfile y Dockercompose, ya realice el codigo de inserción y actualización, hora voy con las pruebas unitarias con Jest, y resulta que no consigo ni se como ejecutar el contenedor para que se inicie y para que arroje los resultados de las pruebas unitarias, aca el docker file:

```
FROM node:14
RUN mkdir -p usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

y aca el contenido de compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '5000:3000'
    external_links:
      - mongo
    volumes: 
      - .:/usr/scr/app
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27018:27017'
    logging: 
      driver: none
```

no consigo ni se como hacer para que se ejecuten las dos cosas, cualquier ayuda de antemano gracias.....

Comment: si quieres que el `run` ejecute los tests sería algo como `CMD ["npm", "run", "test"]` siempre que el packaje.json tenga algo como `"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }`